# Tile based collision detection errors if player is smaller than tiles

Tags: collision-detection, tiles, rust

I have implemented a tilemap where each tile is at a non-negative x and y position. (So at the moment think like chess)

At the moment a tile is `16, 16` pixels in size

`Tile 0,0` is at the **left bottom corner**

Some tiles should be collidable. I've never implemented something like that and during research stumbled upon: https://jonathanwhiting.com/tutorial/collision/

The general idea + collision response handling:

```
let mut new_pos = Point2::new(curr_pos.x + x_offset, curr_pos.y);

let collision_on_x = collide_with_world(&new_pos, &world);

if !collision_on_x  {
    transform.translate_x(x_offset);
}

new_pos.y = curr_pos.y + y_offset;

let collision_on_y = collide_with_world(&new_pos, &world);

if !collision_on_y  {
    transform.translate_y(y_offset);
}
```

The collision detection

```
fn collide_with_world(new_pos: &Point2<f32>, world: &World) -> bool {
    // TODO make these sizes i16 instead so we can grow in any direction!
    let mut left_tile: u16 = (new_pos.x / TILE_SIZE_IN_PIXELS as f32) as u16;
    // -1 so that we do not collide until we are exactly at the thing
    let mut right_tile: u16 = ((new_pos.x + PLAYER_WIDTH - 1.0) / TILE_SIZE_IN_PIXELS as f32) as u16;
    let mut top_tile: u16 = ((new_pos.y + PLAYER_HEIGHT - 1.0) / TILE_SIZE_IN_PIXELS as f32) as u16;
    let mut bottom_tile: u16 = (new_pos.y / TILE_SIZE_IN_PIXELS as f32) as u16;

    println!("new_pos: {:?}, left {}, right {}, top {}, bottom {}", (new_pos.x, new_pos.y), left_tile, right_tile, top_tile, bottom_tile);

    // Useless as long as we use unsigned coordinates
    //if left_tile < 0 {
    //    left_tile = 0;
    //}

    if right_tile > WORLD_WIDTH_IN_TILES {
        right_tile = WORLD_WIDTH_IN_TILES;
    }

    // Useless as long as we use unsigned coordinates
    //if bottom_tile < 0 {
    //    bottom_tile = 0;
    //}

    if top_tile > WORLD_HEIGHT_IN_TILES {
        top_tile = WORLD_HEIGHT_IN_TILES;
    }

    let mut any_collision = false;

    for i in left_tile..=right_tile {
        for j in bottom_tile..=top_tile {
            let tile = world.get_tile(i, j);
            println!("tile at {:?} is {:?}", (i, j), tile);

            match tile {
                Some(tile) => {
                    if tile == WALL {
                        println!("hit a wall at {:?}!", (i, j));
                        any_collision = true;
                    }
                }
                None => (),
            }
        }
    }

    return any_collision;
}
```

I basically took (or tried to take) the optimised version of the linked blog-entry.

Now to the problems:

If `PLAYER_WIDTH` and `PLAYER_HEIGHT` are both 16.0 - collision works fine

***But note*** that I had to put `-1.0` in the calculation of the `right_tile` and `top_tile`, else the collision for UP and RIGHT would occur one pixel to early (so the player would never touch walls to their top or right)

This change alone makes me a bit suspicious - looks like I made an error there.

The real problems start if the player is smaller than a tile:

In the following screenshots the following rules apply:

*) the `PLAYER_WIDTH` and `PLAYER_HEIGHT` are both `8`
*) Greenish tiles are the only walls!
*) **All the screenshots were taken in ONE run - no parameters were changed during this run!**

1) [image: Trying to collide with right tile] -> Trying to collide with right tile -> overlapping
2) [image: Trying to collide with top tile] -> Trying to collide with top tile -> cannot go any nearer than 4 pixels (half the height of the player)
3) [image: Trying to collide with left tile] -> Trying to collide with left tile -> cannot go any nearer than 4 pixels (half the width of the player)
4) [image: Trying to collide with top tile] -> Trying to collide with top tile -> suddenly overlapping although different tile didn't collide?
5) [image: Trying to collide with bottom tile] -> Trying to collide with bottom tile -> cannot go any nearer than 4 pixels

I cannot grasp 2 and 4 at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Does new_pos define the player's center, or its bottom-left corner? 
Because your checks make sense if it's the corner, but usually location is defined by centers. 
Try this -

```
let width_change = PLAYER_WIDTH /2;  
let height_change = PLAYER_HEIGHT /2; 
let mut left_tile: u16 = ((new_pos.x - width_change) / TILE_SIZE_IN_PIXELS as f32) as u16;
let mut right_tile: u16 = ((new_pos.x + width_change - 1.0) / TILE_SIZE_IN_PIXELS as f32) as u16;
let mut top_tile: u16 = ((new_pos.y + height_change - 1.0) / TILE_SIZE_IN_PIXELS as f32) as u16;
let mut bottom_tile: u16 = ((new_pos.y - height_change) / TILE_SIZE_IN_PIXELS as f32) as u16;
```

Comment: The bottom-left corner. Also note that it works if a player has the same size as a tile.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this an answer also. This example isolates the hit detection to movement in the upward direction only, with further isolation from sprite to a single non playable object. It uses rectangular hit detection. I am placing non playable objects on a tiled background also. The sprite and non playable objects are at the same z-order for now.

else if (up)
{
pGraveyard_Objects->DisplayGraveyardFence();
pGraveyard_Objects->DisplayGraveyardObjects();

```
    // NonPlayableObject npo_pumpkin
    // PlayableObject po_sprite

    po_sprite.x = buzzR->row;
    po_sprite.y = buzzR->col; 
    
    po_sprite.width = TILE_WIDTH; 
    po_sprite.height = TILE_HEIGHT;

    //NonPlayableObject npo_pumpkin;
    npo_pumpkin.x = FENCE_RIGHT;
    npo_pumpkin.y = FENCE_BOTTOM + (TILE_HEIGHT);
    
    npo_pumpkin.width = TILE_WIDTH;
    npo_pumpkin.height = TILE_HEIGHT; 



    if (rectHit(po_sprite, npo_pumpkin)) 
    {
        wave2->Play();
        buzzR->MoveTo(buzzR->row, buzzR->col -= GRANULARITY_IN_Y); // show      
    }
    else
    {
        buzzR->MoveTo(buzzR->row, buzzR->col -= GRANULARITY_IN_Y); // show      
        
    }

}
```

// site source of algorithm
// take from https://github.com/jeffThompson/CollisionDetection
//
BOOL rectHit(SceneObject r1, SceneObject r2)
{
TRACE("rectHit Invoked\n");

```
// are the sides of one rectangle touching the other?


if (r1.x + r1.width >= r2.x &&    // r1 right edge past r2 left
    r1.x <= r2.x + r2.width &&    // r1 left edge past r2 right
    r1.y + r1.height >= r2.y &&    // r1 top edge past r2 bottom
    r1.y <= r2.y + r2.height) {    // r1 bottom edge past r2 top
    return TRUE;
}
return FALSE;
```

}